# netcore: Expecting NU1701 but I get nothing

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm mid in converting a large net472 app (130 projects in solution) to netcoreapp3.0 (currently preview6). Since this is a large WIP, project by project gets changed from `<TargetFrameWork>net472</TargetFrameWork>` to `<TargetFrameWorks>net472;netcoreapp3.0</TargetFrameWorks>` multi compile (if not netstandard already).

For some NuGet packages like `System.Data.SQLite.EF6` or `AlphaFS` I get `NU1701` "Package was restored using netframework 4.x" instead of net core [..]". **Everything OK so far, this was expected.**

### Now to the problem

Some of the NuGet packages *-- luckily all made by me some months ago and so can be changed when I find the problem --* just don't restore a single assembly to the project and so every namespace is just missing. But only for the netcoreapp3.0 build of the very same project which builds fine for the net472 counterpart.

I deleted `obj` and `bin` folders, did a rebuild: Just no warnings or errors regarding the package reference (and no expected NU1701 warning).

The package is referenced as following (no conditionals in .csproj file):

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="repacked.xceed.FileSystem" Version="6.2.0.123" ExcludeAssets="contentfiles" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

The `obj\project.assets.json` file shows that for net472 everything is fine and for netcoreapp3.0 nothing has been imported:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0": {
      "repacked.xceed.FileSystem/6.2.0.123": {
        "type": "package",
        "contentFiles": {
          "contentFiles/any/any/_._": {
            "buildAction": "None",
            "codeLanguage": "any",
            "copyToOutput": false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2": {
      "repacked.xceed.FileSystem/6.2.0.123": {
        "type": "package",
        "compile": {
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Compression.Formats.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Compression.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.FileSystem.Windows.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.FileSystem.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Ftp.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.GZip.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.SSH.Client.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.SSH.Core.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.SSH.Protocols.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.SSH.SFtp.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Synchronization.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Tar.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Zip.v6.2.dll": {}
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Compression.Formats.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Compression.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.FileSystem.Windows.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.FileSystem.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Ftp.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.GZip.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.SSH.Client.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.SSH.Core.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.SSH.Protocols.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.SSH.SFtp.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Synchronization.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Tar.v6.2.dll": {},
          "lib/net461/Xceed.Zip.v6.2.dll": {}
        },
        "contentFiles": {
          "contentFiles/any/any/_._": {
            "buildAction": "None",
            "codeLanguage": "any",
            "copyToOutput": false
          }
        }
      }
[..]
```

**What might I have done wrong what has been working fine for years so far?**

Comment: Contact the vendor of that package(s). .NET Core 3.0 is a new platform (not released yet), so "for years" does not apply to it.

Comment: @LexLi I am the "vendor" of that package: It only is for internal use and packages a licensed component which consists of many assemblies. This way these assemblies can be used through transitive references which bubble up the hierarchy. "For years" means this NuGet package worked without trouble for net461, net462, net47, net471, net472 and will also for net48.

Comment: BTW the same problem would happen for netcore2.0 or netcore2.1 or netstandard2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet's compatibility checks for `netcoreapp` frameworks never matches .NET Framework tfms, just other `netcoreapp` versions and `netstandard`. In .NET Core 2.x and 3.x, when a package does not contain any compatible assets, NuGet will check `target asset fallback` and try asset selection again. If it finds assets this time, it provides the `NU1701` warning.

So, the key is that it only checks target asset fallback if it doesn't select any assets during the direct compatibility asset selection.

[Content files in the package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) use the pattern `contentFiles/{lang}/{tfm}/*` where `{lang}` is the project language, such as cs, vb, or fs, and {tfm} is the target framework.

Your assets file shows the package contains at least one file under `contentFiles/any/any`, meaning it will be eligible for selection for any language that your project uses, and for any TFM your project uses. Therefore, when NuGet completes its asset selection for directly compatible TFMs, it selects at least one `contentFiles` file. Apparently the check to use the target asset fallback happens before excluded assets are excluded, so it doesn't matter that you excluded them in your csproj, NuGet has already decided it doesn't need to apply target asset fallback rules.

Since you say you created these packages, you should be able to resolve the issue by moving all of the `contentFiles/any/any/*` files to `contentFiles/any/net461/*`, since that's the same TFM you used for your `lib` files. That way NuGet won't find anything compatible with `netcoreapp3.0` and will use target asset fallback to select the `net461` libs and content files.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. I'll give that a try as soon as possible.

Comment: Works! (but there was no "any/any" at all but "cs/any". Using "cs/net461" it works now)

Comment: Update: Only the libs get picked up, the content files are missing. I did not notice this till now since all the 100 lib-projects I had to migrate did not use the content files, but the final app (which I reached this week) uses them, but they are missing.